# IIS calls BeginRequest of HttpModule twice. Is it a bug?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, web

### Steps

1. Create empty clean ASP.NET Web App - "MyApp". Deselect all options.
2. Create HttpModule - "MyHttpModule" (by MSDN example):

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Web;

   public class MyHttpModule : IHttpModule
   {
       public MyHttpModule() { }

       public string ModuleName { get { return "MyHttpModule"; } }
       public void Dispose() { }

       public void Init(HttpApplication app)
       {
           app.BeginRequest += ProcessBeginRequest;
       }

       private void ProcessBeginRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
       {
           var ctx = ((HttpApplication)source).Context;

           if (ctx.Request.Path == "/favicon.ico") { return; } // This stuff is handled automatically in current IIS version. So, I wrote this line just in case.

           ctx.Response.Write("Processing request from: " + ctx.Request.Url + "<br />");
           ctx.Response.Flush();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Include it to web.config:

   `<system.webServer>`
       `<modules>`
         `<add name="MyHttpModule" type="MyHttpModule, MyApp"/>`
       `</modules>`
     `</system.webServer>`
4. Run the app
5. Browser shows that `BeginRequest` listener was triggered twice for
   single http reques:

[image: Singe http request execution with profiler]

### Attempts

1. `LogRequest` event listener is executed as expected. But this is not proper name listener for http processing work
2. Changes like this one had no result:

   ```
   app.BeginRequest -= ProcessBeginRequest;
   app.BeginRequest += ProcessBeginRequest;
   ```
3. Not a favicon.ico thing

### Question

**Why event handler of single http request was called twice?**

**How risky it is to start any low-level http request processing with IIS? (that is something more than just logging)**

**PS:**
After surfing the internet I'm thinking this is IIS bug. Am I wrong?
Of course, for low-level processing of http requests and for maximum performance it's better to self-host the application or use some prepared set of components for self-hosting like Katana.
But I wonder if IIS be extended with such stuff safely? Cause I have a bad feeling about it, as now it tells to me stay out of http level, do nothing more than logging there and use IIS configuration only.

Comment: When you access "/" IIS default document module would resolve that to one of the files. I guess that's why your module is called twice. Can you try simply access a certain file instead of "/"? Any file triggers your module twice?

Comment: Yes, after I've added index.html to my site module is triggered 3 times: 1 for ".index.html" and 2 times for "/". If I'm navigating to "/index.html" module is triggered once for "/index.html". What is the outcome? I cannot be sure that HttpModule will be executed once for HttpRequest, as it is executed once per touched file? I'm trying to see the whole picture.

Comment: the whole picture is that you need to fully understand the internal pipeline. I could not recall good public documentation online, but there should be books on such. A module can be reentered if the request goes back to the pipeline.